# Adding a condition in the url

Tags: asp.net

I would line to add a test condition in an asp.net form such that:

1) From page1.aspx I manually add a query string parameter so that I can trigger the rest of the process in test mode like so: page1.aspx?test=true . This flag must be added in the query string.
2) When I click on a asp.net button in page1.aspx, I am redirected to page2.aspx in test mode 
because of teh attached querystring

It seems that I have to work around the postback model of asp.net this is not very straight forward.

Any idea how I can achieve the above behavior?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you need to work around anything for this, but is not very clear what you're after, for #2 it seems all you need is a link with the correct url, such as page2.aspx?test=true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're using a form that posts, but you want to stay in "test" mode.  That is, you're not using HTTP-GET so it's not realistic to pass QS variables around.

What I'd do is stash a variable in your Session to set the user's session test mode.  So adding &test=true would trigger a Session["TestMode"] = true; before you move to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (in server-side code)

```
Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx?Test=" + Request.QueryString["Test"]);
```